# Product of uniformly convex spaces is uniformly convex

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I've been looking for a not too complicated solution to the following problem:

> Let $X,Y$ be uniformly convex Banach spaces and for $1<p<\infty$ define the $p$-direct sum $X \oplus_p Y = X \times Y$ equipped with the norm,
>   $$ \lVert (x,y) \rVert_p = \left( \lVert x \rVert^p + \lVert y \rVert^p\right)^{\frac1p}$$
>   for $x \in X,$ $y \in Y.$ Show that $X \oplus_p Y$ is uniformly convex.

Here we say a Banach space $X$ is uniformly convex if for all $\varepsilon >0,$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in X$ with $\lVert x \rVert , \lVert y \rVert \leq 1,$ $\lVert x -y \rVert > \varepsilon$ implies $\lVert \frac{x+y}2 \rVert < 1-\delta.$

If proving a particular case, say $p=2,$ is significantly easier/simpler I would also be interested in that.

---

I don't have much to say for an attempt, as everything I've tried doesn't get me far. The main issue is that the condition $\lVert (x,y) \rVert_p \leq 1$ doesn't tell us much about the sizes of $\lVert x \rVert$ and $\lVert y \rVert$ which makes it difficult to apply the uniform convexity property of the two spaces.

I did find a proof in [Clarkson's original paper,](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1989630?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) where a generalisation of this result is shown. However I find the proof seems overly complicated and technical, defining a bunch of seemingly arbitrary quantities, passing to subsequences, making careful estimates, etc. I feel there should be a cleaner proof for this special case.

**Edit (11th Nov 2017)**: As pointed out in the comments, my definition of uniform convexity was incorrect. It previously said $\lVert x -y \rVert < \varepsilon$ implies $\lVert \frac{x+y}2 \rVert > 1-\delta$ and has since been fixed.

Comment: Since these $p$ norms are all equivalent, you can actually take $p=1$ or $p=\infty$ (in which case p norm becomes max norm). Say we work with $p=1$, then $\|(x,y)\|_1 \le 1$ implies both $\|x\|\le 1$ and $\|y\| \le 1$ etc

Comment: The last two inequalities in your definition of uniform convexity should be reversed! The argument below uses this incorrect definition and hence is incorrect as well.

Comment: @gerald You're right, my bad. I think a similar proof works however, by considering the $p=1$ norm instead. I'll edit my question and post it as an answer.

Comment: @gerald After some thought, it seems like the statement doesn't straightforwardly from the $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ cases. It does however hold up to an equivalent norm, namely with $p=\infty.$ This is sufficient for my purposes, but I'll leave this question open in case someone finds a simple proof of the general case.